# Pin elements to a div with background-size: cover

Tags: html, css

I have a page that displays a map with some pins placed on places of interest. Markup and style as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="map">
  <div class="pins">
    <a href="#">Pin #1</a>
    ...
    <a href="#">Pin #12</a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent url([image]) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pins {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
{

.pins > a {
  width: 20px;
  height: 31px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

My question is: how can I keep my pins, which are absolutely positioned to specific locations on the map, aligned correctly with the map? I've tried using percentage values for the pin positions but because the map is always centered, the alignments go off as soon as the map starts getting cropped at the sides.

I realise I can implement a JS fix, but I'm wondering if there's a pure HTML/CSS solution to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I like your question!

So what background-size cover does is keeping the perspective of the image.
This way you don't know how the displayed dimensions of the image are.
Execpt you knew the ratio in the first place.

I did some experimenting, with the [fluid-video-padding-bottom *"hack"*](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/).
So imagine a 16/9 map. 
 
All you need is a container that lays exact on top of the image (*or it could be the very same container as in my example)* and behaves the same as background-size cover. Achieved using padding-bottom trick.
The only thing left to do is resize the pins accordingly. (I used viewport based units)

[My example](http://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/xGXbBz).

```
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
```

Instead of using the padding bottom trick, you could use object-fit positioning. Which is not well supported yet.

Comment: You could use another image containing the pins with the same dimensions and placing it over the map also with background-size: cover.
But clicking on them would not be possible.